# Installing broken package phatch that worked on 15.10

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install package called [phatch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/phatch) - image processing application, it has a bug on 16.04 [reported and confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phatch/+bug/1567827), it just won't start. On 15.10 it works great.

Can I install this `phatch` from 15.10 release's mirror? Is there any way this application can run on 16.04 before the bug is patched?

I tried adding this line to my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe
```

I did remove the app and installed it again:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get autoremove phatch
$sudo apt-get install phatch
```

I also tried -t parameter with apt: `$sudo apt-get -t wily install phatch` no results there.

While trying alternative approaches, it allowed me to install some lower versions of dependencies for phatch that I was not allowed before just from xenial release, but application does not work, errors look the same:

```
~$ phatch 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py:8196: GtkWarning: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
  return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 16765, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/pyWx/gui.py", line 1218, in show_frame
    frame = Frame(self.filename, None, -1, ct.TITLE)
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/pyWx/gui.py", line 327, in __init__
    frame.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **keyw)
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/pyWx/wxGlade/frame.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.tree = Tree(self, -1, style=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS|wx.TR_NO_LINES|wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT|wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT|wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/pyWx/wxGlade/frame.py", line 26, in __init__
    set_dirty   = parent.set_dirty,
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/treeEdit.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.CreateImageList(icon_size)
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/treeEdit.py", line 111, in CreateImageList
    self._AddFormToImageList(form, icon_size, icon_disabled)
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/treeEdit.py", line 120, in _AddFormToImageList
    wx_image = pil_wxImage(wxImage_pil(wx_image).resize(icon_size,\
  File "/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/wxPil.py", line 46, in wxImage_pil
    image.fromstring(wx_image.GetData())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 746, in fromstring
    "Please call frombytes() instead.")
Exception: fromstring() has been removed. Please call frombytes() instead.
```

Both Wily and Xenial installs same version of `phatch` - 0.2.7.

Comment: Looks like its about to fail because of wxgtk3.0

Comment: On 15.10 it also uses python-wxgtk3.0 and works,  it also gives these few lines of errors, but works there, so I ruled the wxgtk3.0 out: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py:8196: GtkWarning: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init() return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)`, I have also tried installing python-wxgtk2.8 and uninstalling 3.0 with no results.

Comment: You could try to download the wily packages as .deb files from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=phatch&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) you only would need the to `apt-mark hold` those packages so they wont get upgraded again.

Comment: Just tested it. It is giving me the same errors as 16.04, it looks exactly the same version: 0.2.7.1-3.1: all for both 15.10 and 16.04.

Comment: Ok then I'm out of clues.

Comment: Thank you, very appreciated, Sven's link to patch solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after I updated to 16.04
Here I found a fix, which worked for me!
https://bugs.launchpad.net/phatch/+bug/1538906/comments/4